# Python Crawl Question - Get style attributes specified in a CSS file

Tags: python, css, url

[image]

[image]

The modules used are `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`

The site used is
[naver](https://search.naver.com/search.naver?sm=tab_sug.asiw&where=nexearch&query=eorn+%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&oquery=daegu+%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&tqi=isKKKlp0JXVssgMKn9ossssssX0-203124&acq=eorn+%EB%82%A0%EC%94%A8&acr=1&qdt=0)

The code that got stuck while trying and asked for help,

```
weather_icon = soup.find('div', {'class':'weather_info'}).find(('i', {'class':'wt_icon ico_wt6'}))
```

output:

```
<i class="wt_icon ico_wt6"><span class="blind">구름많음</span></i>
```

I've even called it up, but I don't know how to get the style property (url marked with an arrow).

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to scrape? What url?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.